# ReactJS - loop througt child and than in parent display first 10 child objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-object

I have a problem with getting data from child to parent that is fetched from API

Child:

```
class Carton extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  loading: false,
  matchData: []
};
}
```

Here I'm fetching data from API and updating the state

```
async componentDidMount() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.loading = true;
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        matchData: data.doc[0].data[this.props.sportId].realcategories
      });
    });
}, 500);
```

I have looped through nested objects from API and displayed it in the child but I'm stuck how to get data of nested objects to parent. Here is an example how deep I needed to go to get values that I needed

```
getData() {
      this.state.matchData.map((data, i) =>
      data.tournaments.map((tour, j) =>
        tour.matches.map((matc, k) =>
        //values of objects that i need to render a card in Child component
        )//...
```

My first question is if it's better to practice to fetch data from API in parent and then pass objects to the child?

How to pass those objects  to parent so I  can iterate over and select the first 5 of them for 
example

If anybody has any idea or suggestions, please let me know

Br

Stevo

Answer (score 1):

> My first question is if it's better to practice to fetch data from API in parent and then pass objects to the child?

It depends. If your parent object needs to be aware of the children without any event occurring inside the child (such as a click, focus, blur, etc.), then yes, the API call should occur inside the parent. If that is not the case, and the parent only needs to be aware of what child elements were acted up on the children, then you can use a function passed into the child from the parent.

For instance:

```
class Parent {
  const handleSelection = childData => {
    doSomething(childData)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Child handleSelection={handleSelection} />
    )
  }
}
```

```
class Child {
  render() {
    const { myData } = this.state;
    return(
      <div onClick={() => this.props.handleSelection(myData)} />
    )
  }
}
```

This will pass the data from the child component back out to the parent component when the user clicks on the div in child. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will add an additional caveat: think about performance. Another reason to put the API call inside the parent is so that you only have to make 1 API call to get all the data for the children, instead of one API call per child. This can significantly improve performance.

Comment: Great, better performance, less calls to API, that answers my question about that. thanx to all

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback for the purpose, and create a state variable for **matchData** in the parent component instead. Then pass the **matchData** state to the child. When you make the API call in componentDidMount, make a call to the callback function (defined in the parent), sending the data you fetched from the API as args. And further in the callback function, set the **matchData** state variable, which will then automatically re-render both the parent & the child.

Comment: thanx for suggestion I will try it, there is something to chew on, I 'll get back to you with that. Br